# Changing the ServerAlias gives me an Index Of Page

Tags: .htaccess, apache2.4

I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to Server related stuffs, but basically I'm having the most frustrating problem right now...

My configuration file before being changed:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin xyz@gmail.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/xyz.net/public_html
        ServerName www.xyz.net
        ServerAlias xyz.net

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<Directory "/var/www">
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
```

Which is great, and it sort of worked. Although, going to www.xyz.net would load and you can see the content, however, going to xyz.net would show me an Index Of page. So I changed the config file, just switching the name and alias:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin xyz@gmail.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/xyz.net/public_html
        ServerName xyz.net
        ServerAlias www.xyz.net

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<Directory "/var/www">
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
```

However, this doesn't seem to work, how come I'm still getting an Index Of page? Why is it that www.xyz.net has all the page content, yet xyz.net doesn't?! I'm really confused.

I've been trying to get www to redirect to non-www, at first I presumed it was an error with my .htaccess file, but after trying various methods of redirecting and even doing it in PHP, I presumed it was Apache screwing me over. So here's the code I use for the htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1$1 [L,R=301]
```

**edit**:
Thanks for all the help, but everything loads fine on www.xyz.net, however on xyz.net an `Index Of` page is shown, and there are no indexed items in the list, so presumably it's just an empty web page.

Comment: The domain www. and non-www are pointing to the correct IP, as for Error Logging I can't quite get it to work

Comment: Oh right sorry, when I restart apache, it tells me that RewriteLog is mispelled, or defined by a module not included in the server configuration.

Comment: Ah, fixed the log level thing, turns out what I was using is for older  versions, so I replaced it with `LogLevel rewrite:trace3`

Comment: I don't think it's anything to do with the htaccess, since I have another server set-up very similar to this one, and it runs fine. The problem is that because I've changed the ServerAlias and ServerName it's now showing me an (empty) Index Of page on xyz.net

Comment: Yeah I've been restarting after changing everything. Must just be the bug then, can you give me some guidance on how to install 2.4.9? Just an article or SO question to follow? Thanks

Comment: Okay, cheers anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if there is somewhere another virtualhost with `ServerName: xyz.net`. In such case, that other virtualhost can take precedence over yours virtualhost.

Under Linux based systems, there is a default config file which can contain this `ServerName`. By default, it's location is `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`. The file can be also named `000-default.conf`

Comment: Ahh damn, just realised I've made my question kind of vague. Sorry I'm really tired.

Comment: Don't worry, I am tired as well. It's 4:40am here and I am still working on my code.

Comment: Haha, 3.42 am here and I really want to sleep, but this errors really annoying. Just to clarify, it shows an Index Of page which is empty, so presumably there are no files. Whereas if I add www. it shows the homepage for the website.

Comment: What comes to my mind, is that maybe somewhere is another virtualhost with `ServerName: xyz.net`? In such case, that other virtualhost can take precedence over your virtualhost.

Comment: I do not what operating system do you use, but under Linux there is a file containing the default virtualhost (`/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`). Maybe it can contain `ServerName: xyz.net`?

Comment: I already got it fixed, and yeah I had a custom file under sites-available, and 000-default, as you said seemed to be taking precedence over the one I set.

Comment: Great to hear that it's working now. The answer is updated. Good night!